# Electric chainsaw mill

Tags: chain-saw

Are there any electric chainsaws out there powerful enough to run a Alaskan chainsaw mill? I am looking at the husky 3120xp but they are so expensive.

Comment: Basic answer must be yes, since there's no fixed size for a chainsaw mill. You can do a lot with a little if you're OK with the time it takes, which is to say many cuts that "can't be done" with the wrong saw or blade can actually be done, *as long as you're not expecting it to go as quickly*, And the scale of the operation is going to be a factor — big difference (huge) between planking 12"/30cm larch versus a 39"/1m oak.

Comment: That is the entire idea actually. What is the most powerful electric chainsaw

Comment: Unfortunately, SE sites are not great at being buying guides, as any such information is doomed to be outdated in an internet moment. As for "most powerful", the first thing to consider is what do you mean by "power". There is only so much available horsepower you can get from a 15-20A equivalent circuit, but even then, how that electric potential is translated into rotational energy to drive some load is the devilish details. As @Graphus says, even modest equipment would do the job if one tries not to be a 300lb gorilla. Advise shopping based on more criteria than just "power".

Comment: Though, the imp in me is to suggest that a used bandsaw mill always seems to get better results than even a super-fancy chainsaw mill, especially when milling lumber that has a nail in there somewhere. (It always has a nail in there somewhere.) But that is just me.

Comment: All: this is hieing pretty close to asking for shopping advice, which means it might be off-topic for this SE. Unless the community thinks there is value in turning these comments into an Answer...

Comment: 15 amps at 120v is a little more than 2 hp.  Realistically there will be some losses in the system so figure you'll get about 1.75 hp from a corded electric motor.  (If you're in Europe using 240v then you might be able to get a much more powerful corded saw.)  If this is powerful enough for your uses is a much more complicated question, and we'd need to know what species you're cutting, how big it is, how often you plan on using it, how much you want to mill in one session, and how patient you are.

Comment: I'm assuming you're thinking about a corded saw, since you'd be chewing through batteries trying to do this with any cordless.

Comment: Yes the saw would have to be corded. I was thinking since you can run power tools and hand saws there must be an electric model out there that might be powerful enough to efficiently mill.

Comment: Unfortunately, like most woodworking tools, the 15amp @120v household circuit significantly limits the power you can get out of an electric chainsaw.  Generally nobody makes more powerful handheld electric tools because 240v circuits are usually wired in on a per-use basis, extension cords are heavy and expensive, there isn't as much standardization for the amperage, etc.

Comment: OP has clarified that this is essentially a shopping query so thread should be closed.

Comment: Not looking to buy. Wondering if it exists.

Comment: In terms of power and 110VAC service, you are going to find everything is just short of 15A or just short of 20A, and the differences between models will be negligible. If you have 20A service you can use, that is about all the horsepower you can get. Either adjust your expectations as suggested by @Graphus and take your time, or get a big gas model. Or a bandsaw because "there's a nail in there somewhere".